# How can I differentiate between reserved words and variables using ANTLR?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I'm using ANTLR to tokenize a simple grammar, and need to differentiate between an ID:

```
ID              : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)* ;

fragment DIGIT  : '0'..'9' ;
fragment LETTER : 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' ;
```

and a RESERVED_WORD:

```
RESERVED_WORD : 'class' | 'public' | 'static' | 'extends' | 'void' | 'int' | 'boolean' | 'if' | 'else' | 'while' | 'return' | 'null' | 'true' | 'false' | 'this' | 'new' | 'String' ;
```

Say I run the lexer on the input:

```
class abc
```

I receive two ID tokens for "class" and "abc", while I want "class" to be recognized as a RESERVED_WORD.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever 2 (or more) rules match the same amount of characters, the one defined first will "win". So, if you define `RESERVED_WORD` before `ID`, like this:

```
RESERVED_WORD : 'class' | 'public' | 'static' | 'extends' | 'void' | 'int' | 'boolean' | 'if' | 'else' | 'while' | 'return' | 'null' | 'true' | 'false' | 'this' | 'new' | 'String' ;

ID              : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)* ;

fragment DIGIT  : '0'..'9' ;
fragment LETTER : 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' ;
```

The input `"class"` will be tokenized as a `RESERVED_WORD`.

Note that it doesn't make a lot of sense to create a single token that matches any reserved word: usually it is done like this:

```
// ...

NULL  : 'null';
TRUE  : 'true';
FALSE : 'false;

// ...

ID              : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)* ;

fragment DIGIT  : '0'..'9' ;
fragment LETTER : 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' ;
```

Now `"false"` will become a `FALSE` token, and `"falser"` an `ID`.