# Antlr4: Make grammar work with two identical lexer rules

Tags: python, antlr4

I have grammar:

```
grammar qwe;

query
    : COLUMN OPERATOR value EOF
    ;

COLUMN
    : [a-z_]+
    ;

OPERATOR
    : ('='|'>'|'<')
    ;

STRING_LITERAL
    : [a-zA-Z_]+
    ;

value
    : STRING_LITERAL
    ;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Example query: `total_sales>qwe`.

The problem with that is that `COLUMN` and `value` lexer rules are identical. This causes errors:

[image]

How could I rewrite the grammar to make it work without error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two equal lexer rules, of course. In this case it seems that you should remove the COLUMN rule and treat it as a value, if there's really nothing that distinguishes them.

Another option would be to consider a rule for COLUMN with a number of [reserved words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9726708/2853953), if that's applicable.